Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ' for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'
I want to add a migration but it is not working for me - I get this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'API.Data.DataContext'.'
when adding migration this issue arriving

Screenshot of error:
error image
I am using .NET and VS Code editor for migration.
If you know of any possible solution, please give your valuable input.

Program.cs
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

in program.cs file we must follow proper sequence we cannot add AddDbContext after builder.build() method.
